Existence of very weak solution to the elliptic equation $\partial_i(a^{ij}\partial_j u)=\partial_k\partial_l f$
Let $a^{ij}\in W^{1,n}\cap L^\infty (B^1)$ be uniformly elliptic, i.e. $\lambda|\xi|^2\le a_{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j\le \Lambda |\xi|^2$ for a.e. $x\in B^1$, $\xi\in\mathbb R^n$, where $B_1\subset \mathbb R^n$ is the unit ball. Since $a^{ij}\in VMO(B^1)$, it's well-known that for any $1<p<\infty$, $f\in L^p(B^1)$ there exists a unique solution to the Dirichlet problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_i(a^{ij}\partial_j u)=\partial_k f & \text{in } B_1  \\
u=0 &\text{on } \partial B_1
\end{cases},$$
with $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}\le C\|f\|_{L^p}$. But for $f\in L^p(B^1)$, $\frac n{n-1}<p<\infty$, is it always possible to find a "very weak" solution $u\in L^p_{loc}(B^1)$ of the equation $\partial_i(a^{ij}\partial_j u)=\partial_k \partial_l f$ in the distributional sense (i.e. $$\int_{B^1} u\,\partial_j(a^{ij}\partial_i \phi)=\int_{B^1}f\, \partial_k\partial_l\phi,$$ for any $\phi\in C_c^\infty(B^1)$)?
